# Find number of real roots for all polynomials

Tags: polynomials

We can use Descarte's Rule to find number of negative and positive roots. But it doesn't show kind of roots.

It can be real or complex. Is there any general way that show number of real roots or complex roots ? (If there is one , Please provide a proof)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By constructing the chain of [Sturm polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for a given polynomial $P(x)$, one can figure out how many real roots there are.  For example, take the the polynomial $p_0(x) = x^3 + 2x^2 - x - 2$.  The next polynomial in the chain is $p_1(x) = p_0'(x) = 3 x^2 + 4 x - 1$.  To find the remaining polynomials $p_i(x)$ for $i>2$, we perform polynomial long division of $p_{i-2}(x)$ by $p_{i-1}(x)$, and $p_i(x)$ is the negative of the remainder:
\begin{align*}
p_0(x) = p_1(x) \left( \frac{1}{3} x + \frac{2}{9} \right) + \left( -\frac{14}{9} x - \frac{16}{9} \right) \quad &\Rightarrow \quad p_2(x) = \frac{14}{9} x + \frac{16}{9} \\
p_1(x) = p_2(x) \left( \frac{27}{14} x + \frac{18}{49} \right) + \left( - \frac{81}{49} \right) \quad &\Rightarrow \quad p_3(x) = \frac{81}{49}
\end{align*}
Now, the signs of $p_i(-\infty)$ are $-, +, -, +$ for three sign changes;  and the signs of $p_i(+\infty)$ are $+,+,+,+$ for zero sign changes.  There are therefore $3 - 0 = 3$ real roots for $p_0(x)$.  In fact, it is not too hard to see that $p_0(x) = (x^2 - 1)(x +2)$, so this checks out.

Comment: This way seems very good but it's too long. Do you know any other faster way ?

Comment: We must perform polynomial long division until get the number. Am I right ?

Comment: @S.H.W: If you start off with a polynomial of degree $n$, you'll have to do $n-1$ polynomial long divisions, and you'll end up with a set of $n+1$ polynomials;  the polynomial $p_i(x)$ will be of degree $n-i$.   I am unaware of any faster method.

Comment: I was reading an article about Sturm's method and I find out "Notice that Sturm’s theorem is limited to polynomials that do not have multiple roots." How we can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

[Descarte's rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) only gives an upper bound to the number of positive and negative roots.  The roots it tells you about are all real, but there might be two, four, or any even number less than the value you get.  I don't know of a way to find the number of real roots of a polynomial.  You can take the derivative and if you can find the roots of that you can test the value at the roots to determine where there are sign crossings for the original, but that relies on finding roots to a polynomial as well.  It is of one degree lower, but that may not help.

Comment: For example , If first the polynomial be 7 degree , derivation must be 6 degree and It is very hard to graph the function..

Comment: I don't think graphing is hard, even for high degree polynomials.  A spreadsheet will make it easy.  It can be hard to figure out if there are roots sometimes or the graph just comes close to the axis, but you can zoom in.